# Setting variable for NSDragOperation

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is probably a basic question, but I seem to have a problem with a setting a global variable returned from an NSDragOperation.

In my AppDelegate.h I set:

```
NSString *filesDragged;
```

In my AppDelegate.m I set in PerformDragOperation:

```
filesDragged = [files componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

which returns the file dragged... so far so good! but when I later on want to use this variable in another function it shows up NULL:

```
- (void)useMyVariable:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"%@",filesDragged); // result is NULL
}
```

so my question is do I need to set the fileDragged variable to a property or something, since it's not being used globally as I thought it would?

Comment: Add a private variable like 
@implementation AppDelegate {
 NSString *filesDragged;
}

Comment: @ElTomato: thanks that works!